# UWP app UI freezes

Tags: uwp

My UWP app UI becomes unresponsive after the laptop goes to sleep and manually turned on. None of the break points like `OnSuspended` is hit.
I have a Video feed on the UI from a Web camera.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried stopping it with the debugger to ascertain where it's hanging?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes I tried , but as soon as I click on sleep no debugeer point is hit.

Comment: Does this happen even when the app is running without the debugger attached? And does it happen only with your app, have you tried a different UWP app?

Comment: @MartinZikmund No no every debug point is hit when app is running , I expected the OnSuspended to be hit when I hit the sleep on my system.

Comment: I suggested that you could write some logs in `OnSuspended`, and start your app from start menu instead of using visual studio to debug. Then you could check if there're some logs that have been generated after the laptop goes to sleep and manually turned on.

Answer (score 0):

`OnSuspended` is never called when debugging in Visual Studio, you can only trigger it manually. See the bottom note at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/suspend-an-app